# cannot load such file -- app/models/member.rb (LoadError)

Tags: cucumber, nitrousio

I have this step-defenition :

```
require 'app/models/member.rb'

When(/^roelof is a member$/) do    
    Member.where (name: 'Roelof')
end
```

but when I do cucumber I see the error messsage in the title. 
Anyone know what I did wrong ?

Roelof

Edit : you can see the project here : https://github.com/roelof1967/wissel-finance

Comment: Why you require this file? You can use Member class anyway.

Comment: No, when I delete that part I see this error : uninitialized constant Member NameError).

Comment: hm, i don`t see features/support/env.rb file.
read this topic maybe it help you
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: We can't actually see the project, you've probably set it to private.